# Nodejs passport setup confusion

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js

I have been trying to setup my Nodejs MySQL database configuration. I found [this](https://gist.github.com/manjeshpv/84446e6aa5b3689e8b84) passport.js config for MySQL on Github. The config works properly but there is a part that I do not understand.

```
var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users ( email, password ) values ('" + email +"','"+ password +"')";
                    console.log(insertQuery);
                connection.query(insertQuery,function(err,rows){
                newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

                return done(null, newUserMysql);
                });
```

I am confused about the `insertID` field. The table I am using does not have a field called insertID. It does however have a field named ID. I tried changing that line to

```
newUserMysql.id = rows.Id;
```

bu doing so gives me:

> Error: Failed to serialize user into session

Leaving it as it is gives me no error

Looks like `insertID` has nothing to do with the `ID` field of my table but I do not understand what it means

Comment: **WARNING**: To avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) always escape *any* arbitrary data in your query by using [placeholder values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values).

Comment: That code is not only old, it's recklessly oblivious to  composing queries properly with placeholder statements. It shouldn't be used. The safer way to do this is to define a User model, for example with [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com), and use that to persist your data. Don't forget to use a proper password hash like [Bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) to properly hash your passwords. **Never** save them as plain-text.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that but I still do not understand how insertID works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That probably represents [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) which is the ID of the last row inserted.

The response of an `INSERT` is not "rows" but a result object, so maybe better named it'd be:

```
connection.query("...", function(err, result) {
  newUserMysql.id = result.insertId;

  return done(null, newUserMysql);
});
```

It's important to note that using Promises dramatically simplifies your code, and `async`/`await` can take that even further. This could be as simple as:

```
let result = await connection.query("...");

newUserMysql.id = result.insertId;

return newUserMysql;
```

Where that's inside an `async function` with a Promise-driven database library like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com). You're not handling the potential errors in your first case. In the second you'll get exceptions which will wake you up when there's problems.